# How to make TCP chat server have multiple clients

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I currently have a client and a server that react to each other perfectly. I am just confused about how to make threads to allow multiple clients. I have posted my two classes, and when testing in the terminal, they work well. I am stuck on how to properly add a new class that will support multiple clients, also to keep the functionality the same. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int port = 1234;
        String input;
        String count;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.print("Please Enter an Input: ");
                input = inFromUser.readLine();
                if(input.equals("exit"))
                {
                    outToServer.writeBytes(input + '\n');
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    outToServer.writeBytes(input + '\n');
                    count = inFromServer.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Total Number of Messages: " + count);
                    System.out.print("");
                }
            }
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Make sure the server is on as well.");
        }
    }
}



import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ProjectServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int count = 0;
        int port = 1234;
        String messageFromClient;
        try
        {
            
            System.out.println("The TCP server is on.");
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            while (true) {
                
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                messageFromClient = inFromClient.readLine();
                if (messageFromClient.equals("exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println("The message is: " + messageFromClient);
                System.out.println("Your IP address is listed as: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                System.out.println("your port number is: " + port);
                System.out.println("");

                String currentCount = Integer.toString(count);
                outToClient.writeBytes(currentCount + '\n');
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Server is no longer available");
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: the most basic answer is you need to call welcomeSocket.accept() again. Remember the open sockets and deal with them (you could start a thread for each client, but that is just one option)

Answer (score 0):

Putting Andi's comment into some piece of code:

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ProjectServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        int port = 1234;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("The TCP server is on.");
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true) {
                Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

                Runnable task = () -> {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());

                    while (true) {
                        String messageFromClient;

                        try {
                            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                            messageFromClient = inFromClient.readLine();
                            if (messageFromClient.equals("exit"))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            count.incrementAndGet();
                            System.out.println("The message is: " + messageFromClient);
                            System.out.println("Your IP address is listed as: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                            System.out.println("your port number is: " + port);
                            System.out.println("");

                            String currentCount = Integer.toString(count.get());
                            outToClient.writeBytes(currentCount + '\n');

                        } catch(IOException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                };

                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Server is no longer available");
        }
    }
}
```

1. I wrapped some of your ProjectServer functionality into Runnable task.
2. Client-side remains as it is.
3. I replaced `int count` with `AtomicInteger` to prevent a race condition. You can use any mutual exclusion mechanisms though.
4. First run the server, then a couple of clients.
5. NOTE: I do not handle exceptions beautifully, and do not perform any code refactoring.